# PCA and Hotelling's T2 in Python

Tags: python, statistics, pca

I am trying to plot a Hotelling's T2 in Python and would like to plot like the one below in R.

[PCA and Hotelling's T^2 for confidence intervall in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637860/pca-and-hotellings-t2-for-confidence-intervall-in-r)

And I saw a comment(link below) helping with that, in Python. But a more detailed suggestion or answer would be helpful.

[Python PCA plot using Hotelling's T2 for a confidence interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732075/python-pca-plot-using-hotellings-t2-for-a-confidence-interval)

Thanks in advance.

Shyam

Comment: please don't use the R-tag when you want a python solution.

Comment: Ok. Thank you..

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25412954/hotellings-t2-scores-in-python